# Combine a text pattern and a numeric greater-than comparison in a single ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I know how to search for an exact match in ElasticSearch:

```
GET world/country/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "GAIN" : "10"
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to do a numeric greater-than comparison, and combine it with a text pattern search. In SQL I would write this:

```
WHERE GAIN > 10 AND DESCRIPTIONLIKE '%good%'
```

How do I do the equivalent in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

To search for `GAIN > 10` you'll need a [Range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-range-query.html).

To search for `DESCRIPTION LIKE '%good%'` you'll need to ensure that the description field is analyzed in a way that tokenizes it; then you could just use a regular match query on it, which would find documents that contain the word `good` (but not `goodbye` -- depending on the analyzer, but I assume you want word-boundary tokenization).

To combine the two conditions you'll need a [Bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Comment: Range query is the one I need. But cant understand searching string i.e. 2nd one, can u help writing query

Comment: It's a regular match query: `{ "match": { "description": "good" } }`, but you'll have to make sure the description field is _analyzed_. Take a look at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html